# Trying to change line thickness with matplotlib.mpatches.Patch

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, figure

I am manually making a legend as there are too many inputs in my figure, so I use matplotlib.mpatches.Patch to make legend using:

```
orange_patch = mpatches.Patch(color='orange', label='n=505 distribution', lw = 1)

grey_patch = mpatches.Patch(color = 'grey', label = 'n=100 sampled 100 times', lw = 1)

plt.legend(handles=[orange_patch, grey_patch], frameon = False)
```

This works, but the lines are very thick.  Changing linewidth with "lw" changes the length and width of the line.  I am looking to make the line thinner while preserving the length, similar to the thickness shown on the graph.  Anyone know how to do this?

[image: upper left shows legend I am trying to change]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the thickness (height of the patch) is not to your liking, you can use line2D instead. Documentation [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.lines.Line2D.html). Here is the updated code for your reference.... Use `lw` (float) to adjust the thickness

```
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D

myHandle = [Line2D([], [], color='orange', lw = 3), Line2D([], [], color='gray', lw = 3)]

plt.legend(handles = myHandle, labels=['n=505 distribution', 'n=100 sampled 100 times'], frameon = False)
```

[image]

Comment: This is a good and easy solution!